# Route in Laravel to send data into url

Tags: php, laravel-4

When we want to send data into url for example:

```
http://localhost:8000/routine/6
```

we use route like:

```
Route::get('/routine/{id}',array('as' =>'routine'), function($id)
{
    //code here
});
```

Now I have a problem when I am trying to send data like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/routine.php?data=Data1&data2=Data120
```

what will be the route in Laravel???

and how to get this data?????

Answer (score 0):

The route that will be called is

```
Route::get('/routine',array('as' =>'routine'), function($id)
{
    $data = Input::get('data')
    $data2 = Input::get('data2')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the route like the example i had shown below where name is url parameter like your data

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function($name = 'John')
{
    return $name;
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, if the code answers the question, etc.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.